# Who belongs to this book?

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to say

> Who belongs to this book?

or is it mean like book has somebody and who is the guy the book has?

Comment: To whom does this book belong? or beginning with "whom" and finishing with to. (I am not a native but I would say that.) You can also do it easier, "whose book is this?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatical.

> 1. Who belongs to this book?

is asking who the book has in its possession: Who is this person that the book has? I cannot think of a context in which someone would belong to a book, so this sentence doesn't make much sense.

---

> 2. Who does this book belong to?

This sentence is asking who has the book in their possession: Who is the person that has the book? This sentence makes sense and is probably what you wanted.

---

(From a comment)

> 3. To whom does this book belong?

This version is grammatical and markedly formal in comparison to sentence 2; i.e., it might sound stilted in everyday conversation. It means the same thing as the second example.

---

(From the same comment)

> 4. Whom does this book belong to?

A fairly rare construction in comparison to sentences 2 and 3, and not as formal-sounding as sentence 3. It means the same thing as sentence 2, however.

Comment: only option left is that " to who does this belong"

Comment: @Mrt That would be ungrammatical because the word ***who*** is the object of the preposition ***to***, and in that case it changes into its object form, *whom*. Further, the *to* at the end of the sentence is superfluous and would render the sentence ungrammatical even if we changed *who* into *whom*. So you have the nominative version (*who*) instead of the accusative one (*whom*), and the extra *to* at the end. (Edit: Okay, you've edited out the extra *to* at the end – the first reason why the sentence is ungrammatical remains.)

Comment: I edited my comment because I wrote the "to" at the by mistake.